# Upgrade from Windows 7 OEM Home to 7 Ultimate using Vista to 7 Ultimate 64-bit upgrade disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, upgrade

I'd like to upgrade from Windows 7 OEM Home to Windows 7 Ultimate using Windows Vista to Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit upgrade disk.

Can this be done?

Comment: If my answer fixes your issue, feel free to mark it as correct. If not, can you add a comment so we can improve?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. There is no "Vista to Windows 7" only upgrade. It is simply a Windows 7 Upgrade disk

Comment: I have done this and it works fine, just need valid product key.